# How can I add multiple images for dynamic ExpandableListView?

Tags: android

My code:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_list_view,null);
        }

        ImageView imgListChild = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_icon);
        if(mObjectList[childPosition].getFlagStatus()==2){
            imgListChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_2);
        }if(mObjectList[childPosition].getFlagStatus()==1){
            imgListChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_1);
        }if(mObjectList[childPosition].getFlagStatus()==0){
            imgListChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

What I want is like this:

[image]

But it will make all the ImageViews visible and have the same image if I code like above. Please show me how to fix this. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

why dont you add specific image to specific specific child

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_list_view,null);
    }

    ImageView imgListChild = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_icon);
    if(childPosition==0)
    {
         imgListChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
    }
    /*And so on*/
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Because this is a dynamic listview (I get objects from database and show them on this list) ,so add specific image at specific postion is impossible.